# Subsubsection numbers go missing

Tags: numbering, labels, subsection

When I set the subsubsection so that the text runs on from the heading, the subsubsection numbers don't appear. Adding the  command to number to depth 3 doesn't help. Is there anything I can do other than manually add each label?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

%Styles for sections and (sub-)subsections
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\itshape}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\normalsize\itshape}{}{0em}{}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\normalsize\itshape}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{18pt}{6pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{12pt}{0pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}

%Add dot after section numbers but not (sub-)subsection numbers
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\titleformat{\section}
 {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{.} 
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
This is the start of a section.

\subsection{Subsection}
This is the start of a subsection.

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}\label{3.1.1}

This is a subsubsection, but the number's missing.

\subsubsection{1.1.2\quad Another subsubsection}\label{3.1.2}
This is a subsubsection manually numbered to look roughly as it should. Why is the label for \S\ref{3.1.1} not showing?

\paragraph{Paragraph}
For completeness.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Also, I noticed that there is a `\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}` in your first set of styles which is later overwritten by the `\titleformat{\section}
 {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}` just below the import subfigure package. I edited it out of the answer I submitted as well.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to have been a missing parameter for your `\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\normalsize\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{0.5em}{}`. Unlike the `\titleformat*{}` the numbering parameter has to be passed to it manually.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

%Styles for sections and (sub-)subsections
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\itshape}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\normalsize\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\normalsize\itshape}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{18pt}{6pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{12pt}{0pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}

%Add dot after section numbers but not (sub-)subsection numbers
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{.} 
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Section}
    This is the start of a section.
    
    \subsection{Subsection}
    This is the start of a subsection.
    
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection}
    
    This is a subsubsection, but the number's missing.
    
    \subsubsection{Another subsubsection}
    This is a subsubsection manually numbered to look roughly as it should. Why is the label for not showing?
    
    \paragraph{Paragraph}
    For completeness.
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. I removed the asterisk from \titleformat*{subsubsection} because it was throwing up errors - 'Missing \begin{document}' and 'Entered in horizontal mode' - and I assumed that the non-asterisked version was needed for the 'runin' formatting, since that seemed to be the only way to get it to compile. Was I wrong? And is there any reason for preferring the asterisked or non-asterisked version in the first place?

Comment: You are absolutely right to have used non-asterisk for the runin feature. As an example from your code `\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\itshape}` renders identical to `\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalsize\itshape}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}`. The former is easier to read and more convenient to write, especially if you are only making small changes from the default behavior. But ultimately, between brevity and specificity (unless you are sharing your code) the only thing that matters is what works for you and gets the results you want.